# How to combine 2 index view into 1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Index view ( shows all the data created for it's own model)

## generatorscontroller.rb

```
def index 
    @generators = Generator.all
  end
```

## resultscontroller.rb

```
def index
    @results = Result.all
  end
```

I want to have an index page whereby i can view all the data of Generators along with the data of Results. How should i do that ?

I have 2 models - Generators and Results.

Generator has_many :results

Result belongs_to :generator

Data of Generators :

[image]

Data of Results :

[image]

What i want is to have the image shown below , together with the values. The values are now generated in seperated page (index for generators and index for results ) . What i want is to merge them together .

[image]

Comment: make partials and include them where needed

Comment: HungryCoder : can u tell me more bout the method u just suggested ?

Comment: How to write the partial code ? I seen some tutorials they usually render to those files tat's in the same directory . But for my case how should i render ? i have views/Generator/index.html.erb and views/Results/index.html.erb  how should i render them ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of posibilites:

1. Create a controller, for example, results_geneators_controller.rb and do the two querys
2. Make a view into your database with an union and you will have one controler with one query and with one index
3. Show results throught generators into your view to build the table columns.
4. Build a hash in your controller whith the final results you are looking for your table.

Comment: j.avi How do you do the 3rd choice ? I've seen many examples but all those doesn't work. I get back an error message saying undefine method 'ncbi_ref_seq' when i called generator.results.ncbi_ref_seq ( 1 of the attribute data in my Result )

Comment: in my controller index i've tried @results = Result.include(:generators) . And in the view index i tried calling result.generator.primer_length ( but it gives me undefine method primer_length) ... Primer length is an attribute belongs to the Generator class

Comment: Probably build a hash will solve you problem, for example, @generators.each do... result = Result.find_by_generator_id... build the hash structure you need to iterate into your view

Comment: Ummm... i'm thinking, this attributes are accesibles, protected...?

Comment: the attributes are accessible. FOr generator.rb 

attr_accessible :results_attributes,:choice, :primer_length, :random_primer_generated, :genome_sample, :generator_id

for Result.rb:

attr_accessible :ncbi_ref_seq,:genome_seq, :genome_sample

Comment: j.avi where should i place the  result = Result.find_by_generator_id ? in my Result index controller  ?

Comment: Javi How should i do the first suggestion u suggested. i understand about the contorller but how to do the 2 query ? WHat query are u suggesting ?

Comment: In yout Generators_controller you can build the hash like: `@my_resutls = {}
    Generators.all.each do |generator|
        results = Results.find_by_generator_id(generator.id)
        unless results.blank?
        @my_resutls[generator.id] = [] unless @my_resutls.include? generator.id
        @my_resutls[generator.id] << {:generator => generator, :resulsts => results}
        end
    end`
Then in your view, you can iterate `@my_results` and show the data in the way you want.

Comment: not working... @my_results.each do |result| , the error stated each undefined method